# The program doesn't end when the timer ends until you give an input

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, timer

I had some free time and I decided to make a program that could give me math questions using Java Eclipse. Whenever the timer ends during it though, the while loop doesn't end until you give one last input. I know that it is because of the while loop, but I don't know how to end it.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class math_questioner_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstnumber,secondnumber,operation,answer,answerinput,correctcount = 0,incorrectcount = 0, time, difficulty, max = 0, mixedop;
        Scanner input;
        System.out.println("What do you want the operation to be? 1 = addition 2 = subtraction 3 = multiplication 4 = division 5 = mixed");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        operation = input.nextInt();
        // There is around 30 lines that don't relate to the question here
        if (operation == 1) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (time*1000);
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                firstnumber = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
                secondnumber = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
                answer = firstnumber + secondnumber;
                System.out.println("What is " + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + "?");
                answerinput = input.nextInt();
                if (answerinput == answer) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    correctcount++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, " + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " is " + answer + ".");
                    incorrectcount++;
                }
            }
        // Another 140 lines here that don't matter either, just some operations
        if (time == 1) {
            System.out.println("You got " + correctcount + " questions correct and " + incorrectcount + " wrong in " + time + " second!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You got " + correctcount + " questions correct and " + incorrectcount + " wrong in " + time + " seconds!");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it's because of the while loop that it won't end, but I don't know how. Also please don't yell at me. I'm a beginner that takes classes at my Chinese school, it's only my 9th week (I've been to nine classes) and this is random extra stuff. I get most of my answers from this website and I also have only learned to do things with integers. It's also my first question here.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the while loops fault, as you can't evaluate the exit condition until after you've input something - ie, you can't timeout the user input itself

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using `Scanner#nextLine` and either another `Scanner` or `Integer#parseInt` to parse the result, as you are potentially leaving new line characters in the buffer which can cause issues the next time you try and scan a value

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm a beginner and have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: `Scanner#nextInt` is a blocking method, it won't return till has something to return, you can't check the state of the timeout (`while-loop`) until that method has returned

Comment: I've tested `while-loop` logic and works just fine, BUT, it can't be evaluated until AFTER there is input from the user, so I would wait 10 minutes at the prompt, until I enter something, the loop condition won't be evaluated, even if the timeout is just 1 minute

Comment: I know that, that's my problem!

Comment: That's a limitation of console development, there's nothing you can do about it. You could try using a GUI like Swing or JavaFX, but those are complex subjects. You could also determine if the input as after the timeout and invalidate it, but that's about it (you really don't want to start discussing the possibility of using threads ... and I don't really want to consider how it might be done :P)

Comment: So should I just forget about it? I guess it might be easier.

Comment: You could think differently about it. You could, before you ask a question and after the user answers it, determine if the timeout has occurred and simply discard that result, as an idea